# Implementing service contract Magento 2 deletebyid()

Tags: magento2, resource-model

Implementing service contract using this method getting error of "Class string does not exist."

model/userrepository.php

```
 public function deletebyid($del)
    {
        $hamburger = $this->hamburger;
        $hamburger->load($del);
        if (! $hamburger->getId())
        {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Unable to find hamburger with ID "%1"', $del));
        }
         return $hamburger->delete();
    }
```

api/userrepositoryinterface.php

```
/**
 * @param int $del
 * @return string
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function deletebyid($del);
```

../etc/webapi.xml

```
  <route method="GET" url="/V1/del/:del">
        <service class="Assign\RestService\Api\HamburgerRepositoryInterface" method="deletebyid"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
```

i must be not using delete function properly...but i am not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update you interface like below.

```
/**
 * @param int $del
 * @return Assign\RestService\Api\Data\HamburgerInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function deletebyid($del);
```

If you want to return any boolean value then just write as @return bool and in other case use any custom or core interface like above in this case your function should return defined type object. Let me know in case further help needed.

Comment: Hi @asad was my answer helpful for you?

Comment: Hi @asad I saw your edit, generally it returns boolean value and it depends on requirement whether you want to returns any object in response or not.

Comment: yeah i tried that but "@return Assign\RestService\Api\Data\HamburgerInterface" this return type solve my problem. Even i haven't write any code in this ../Api\Data\HamburgerInterface file but it require this in return

Comment: if you write its return type as bool then this function should return any bool value, and in your case if you defines it as any data interface then it should return data interface object. I hope this will clear everythings.

Comment: I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: yeah i edited it for futher use...

Comment: thanks for the reply. i will be in touch with you

Comment: Please accept it and give an upvote, in case it was useful for u. it'll help others.

Comment: i can't up-vote it , don't have much reputation

Comment: but you can accept this answer as it is asked by you.

Comment: i am new in magento  so dont know much about it.......i i want to use save() function but dont know syntax of it..would you help in that?

Comment: yep accepted.....i am new so don't know much about all stuff :p